# How to show all deployments/daemonsets which mount specific configmap/secret?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Sometimes, I want to explore all deployments/daemonsets which mount specific configmap/secret.

Is there any way can achieve this by `kubectl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `jq` to do such a complex queries.
Here you go:

```
kubectl get -o json deploy,daemonset | jq '[.items[] | . as $parent | .spec.template.spec.volumes[]? | select(.configMap != null) | {kind:$parent.kind, name:$parent.metadata.name, configMap:.configMap.name}]'
```

The `jq` command de-constructed:

```
[ // output as array
  .items[] // iterate over root key 'items'
  | 
  . as $parent // store the current entry as $parent to refer to it later
  | 
  .spec.template.spec.volumes[]? // iterate over its volumes (the ? to prevent error if there is no volume
  | 
  select(.configMap != null) // select only those volumes with configMap key 
  | 
  {kind:$parent.kind, name:$parent.metadata.name, configMap:.configMap.name} // now construct the output using $parent's kind and name and the configMap's name
]
```

Example output:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "name": "telemetry-agent",
    "configMap": "telemetry-config-map"
  },
  {
    "kind": "DaemonSet",
    "name": "fluent-bit",
    "configMap": "fluent-bit"
  },
  {
    "kind": "DaemonSet",
    "name": "telegraf",
    "configMap": "telegraf"
  }
]
```

N.B. If you want to find specific configMap, just replace the `select()` clause `.configMap != null` to `.configMap.name == "specific-configmap"`. Also, feel free to add `--all-namespaces` to the `kubectl get` command if you want to query from all namespaces